# Any polynomial ring contains a prime element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

It is true that for a polynomial ring $R[x]$, there will be a prime element?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [still no](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2194644/any-commutative-ring-always-contains-at-least-one-prime-elements) (even though one comment suggested otherwise), consider $R=\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ and $R[t] = \mathbb C[x,y,t]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$

All prime ideals of $R[t]$ are of the form $(x,y,t-c)$ or $(x,y)$.

Comment: Holy cow! How did you come up with this example?

Comment: @AlexM. The less prime ideals a ring has, the easier it should be to control them. Hence I picked $R$ to be a ring with only one single prime ideal, which has to be of course non-principal, i.e. a zero-dimensional local ring with at least a two-dimensional co-tangent space. Of course one should try a two-dimensional example first, i.e. the natural choice is $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$. To have more control of the prime ideals of $R[t]$, I picked the field to be algebraically closed, but I think this example should work over abitrary fields.